# Can I have two different build configurations use the same config transform file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-config-transform

In my production environment, I have to setup two different sites:
- www.mysite.com
- beta.mysite.com
The www.mysite.com is my prorduction site, while beta.mysite.com is actually a "beta" version of the site. All the settings in the web.config are exactly the same between the two sites (same app settings, point to the same database etc...), just a small difference in the code that is vary against build configuration:in Production build configuration I've defined a compilation symbol "PRODUCTION" to have the site direct to https when user open the Login page.

```
#if PRODUCTION
[RedirectToHttps]
#endif
public ActionResult LoginPage()
{
    //code to render the HTML of the Login page
}
```

I don't want to manage two config transform files with the same content. So is there anyway I can have multiple build configurations use the same config transform file ?

Comment: You may get some ideas from here:  http://alandean.blogspot.com/2011/02/framework-version-targeting-with.html